# layout-xlarge being ignored using Nexus 10 emulator in Android Studio 1.4.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using Android Studio version 1.4.1.

I have the following 2 layout xmls in my layout-large dir:

**activity-main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="com.hfad.workout.WorkoutListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list_frag"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hfad.workout" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hfad.workout"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

Here are the emulator details from Android Studio:

```
Name: Nexus_10_API_23

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: /Users/rt/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_23.avd

Target: Google APIs (API level 23)

Skin: nexus_10

SD Card: /Users/rt/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_23.avd/sdcard.img

Snapshot: no

hw.lcd.density: 320

hw.dPad: no

hw.initialOrientation: landscape

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.camera.back: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 200M

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

runtime.network.latency: none

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.keyboard: yes

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.device.hash2: MD5:47dc70fd92541dd16c19f9efa3e9db62

hw.ramSize: 1536

tag.id: google_apis

tag.display: Google APIs

hw.sdCard: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.device.name: Nexus 10

hw.battery: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: no

AvdId: Nexus_10_API_23

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

hw.camera.front: none

hw.gps: yes

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 10 API 23

snapshot.present: no

vm.heapSize: 128

runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

When I run my app in the Nexus 10 emulator however, its using the layouts defined in the **layout** dir instead of the **layout-xlarge** dir. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use layout-sw720dp.or  layout-sw800dp.

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti, didn't work though :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed this by going into the AVD Manager > Edit this AVD > Show Advanced Settings > Custom skin definition

Change the skin from "nexus_10" to "No Skin"

Comment: This is the correct answer, the nexus_10 skin is (still) buged

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and after some research, I can say this is a known issue with android studio. The large and xlarge layouts are correctly displayed in the preview (in the IDE), but not with the emulators (it takes the normal layout xml). You should use a real phone, but I know that not everybody has an android phone.